# How to disable bold (font weight) globally in emacs?

Tags: emacs, fonts, bold

I hate bold text while coding. Is it possible to disable bold text (and underline) in every single file and emacs's interface?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way is probably

```
(set-face-bold-p 'bold nil)
```

Another possibility, which also deals with underlines, would be to evaluate the following snippet in a running Emacs session:

```
 (mapc
  (lambda (face)
    (set-face-attribute face nil :weight 'normal :underline nil))
  (face-list))
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Terminal.app, you can also go into your Preferences->Settings. For your current settings, go to the Text group and simply uncheck "Use bold fonts." Screenshot below:

[image]