# How can I change fonts of elements between HTML tags in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, fonts

I have this in my .emacs: `(set-frame-font "Consolas-10")`

and I also tried this: `(set-frame-font "Consolas-10")`

But the font between the `<h2>`tags are not Consolas (or maybe Italic Consolas):

[alt text http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/6865/emacs2.jpg](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/6865/emacs2.jpg)

How can I change the font of elements between html tags (or disable italics, bold, etc.)?

Comment: Can you tell us what mode you are using (e.g. nxml-mode) for editing index.html? The details, like font and colour, of font-lock support (i.e. syntax highlighting in emacs-speak) are usually mode-specific settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064904/how-to-disable-bold-font-weight-globally-in-emacs) it seems to me that you should be able to use the same idea and simply disable the use of italics on font faces (include all the other setting from that other question if you want to disable bold and underline as well):

```
(mapc
  (lambda (face)
    (set-face-attribute face nil :slant 'normal))
  (face-list))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I still don't understand most of emacs terminology such as face-list, lambda, slant, etc.

Comment: In the above lambda defines an anonymous function that takes one argument - face. That function is then applied to each element returned by the function call (face-list) by the mapc function. Finally, the body of the anonymous function calls set-face-attribute on the given face, setting attributes for that face. A face in emacs-speak is a font used in a specific semantic context, e.g. to highlight the contents of a h2 html tag in this case. A face has properties like font, size, weight, slant and so on. You can access the documentation of functions with C-h f <fn name>.