# Disable italic in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, fonts, elisp, emacs-faces

I would really like to have the italic style disabled in Emacs.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064904/how-to-disable-bold-font-weight-globally-in-emacs) post it is explained how to disable bold and underline, but not italic.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Using tab-completion, I can see I have these available

```
set-face-background          set-face-background-pixmap
set-face-font              set-face-foreground
set-face-inverse-video-p    set-face-stipple
set-face-underline        set-face-underline-p
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually done in a very similar manner:

```
(set-face-italic-p 'italic nil)
```

Refer to the function's documentation for further details(C-h f set-face-italic-p)

Comment: I can see the help screen, that you described, but for some reason, I don't have the ´set-face-italic-p´. When I do tab-completion on ´set-face´ I get those listen in the question. Do I need to install something? I use Linux.

Comment: set-face-italic-p is not an interactive function, so you can only call it by evaluating the above expression (put cursor behind the closing bracket, do C-x C-e). You cannot call it using M-x, which is why you don't see it when doing tab-completion.

Answer (score 6):

Since [emacs 24.4](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/set-face-italic-p.html):

```
(set-face-italic 'font-lock-comment-face nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
M-x customize-face RET italic RET
```

Change the `slant` property to "normal."

An ugly hack (bug or feature?) is to use a font that has no italic, like Terminus.  That's what I use.  I have sometimes set italic to inherit from variable-pitch instead of default and that creates an italic when the font has no slanted version.

Comment: If you happen to install the oblique version of the font, that hack will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

emacs 25.x here:

```
M-x make-face-unitalic <ENTER>
default  <ЕNTER>   # <- your answer to "Make which face unitalic:"
```

Sometimes the above does not work, then try these extra commands:

```
C-x h      # select all of the text
M-x make-face-unitalic  < ENTER>
<ENTER>    # <-- selects the default option to apply it to whole region
C-g        # deselect region
```